# Trigonometry limit:: $\lim _ { x \rightarrow \pi/2 } \frac { \ln \sin x } { \cos ^ { 2 } x }$

Tags: limits

$$\lim _ { x \rightarrow \frac { \pi } { 2 } } \frac { \ln \sin x } { \cos ^ { 2 } x }$$

I need to find the limit without using L'Hopital's theorem

I tried to solve the limit using the first remarkable limit, but I couldn't find an equivalent function because $x$ tends to $\pi/2$ and not to zero. In general, I'm at a dead end

I would be grateful if you specify the true path

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Since $\ln (1+s) \sim s$ as $s \to 0$ we get $\lim_{s\to 0} \frac {\ln (1+s)} {1-(1+s)^{2}}=-\frac 1 2$. Now put $s=\sin x-1$ in this.

Comment: why did cos become 1-(1+t)^2?

Comment: @KonstantinPodyganov $1-(1+s)^{2}=1-\sin^{2}x=\cos^{2}x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim _ { x \to \frac { \pi } { 2 } } \frac { \ln \sin x } { \cos ^ { 2 } x }\\
=\lim _ { x \to \frac { \pi } { 2 } } \frac { \ln( \sin x -1 +1)} { 1-\sin ^ { 2 } x }\\
=\lim _ { x \to \frac { \pi } { 2 } } \frac { \ln( 1+ \sin x -1)} { -(\sin x-1)(1+\sin x) }\\
=\frac{-1}{2}$$
As $x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}, \sin x \rightarrow 1$

Answer (score 2):

Let $t= \sin x$. Then we have to compute

$$\lim_{t \to 1} \frac{ \ln t}{1-t^2}.$$

We have

$$\frac{ \ln t}{1-t^2}=\frac{ 1}{1+t} \cdot \frac{ \ln t}{1-t}.$$

It is clear that $\frac{ 1}{1+t} \to 1/2$ as $t \to 1.$

Let $t=e^s$, then

$$\lim_{t \to 1} \frac{ \ln t}{1-t}= \lim_{s \to 0} \frac{s}{1-e^s}.$$

If $f(s):= e^s,$ then

$$ \frac{e^s-1}{s}= \frac{f(s)-f(0)}{s-0}=f'(0)=1.$$

Hence $\lim_{s \to 0} \frac{s}{1-e^s}=-1$

This gives

$$\lim _ { x \rightarrow \frac { \pi } { 2 } } \frac { \ln \sin x } { \cos ^ { 2 } x }=-1/2.$$

Answer (score 1):

I have a lenthier method, put sinx=$e^t$ As x→π/2,sinx→1, so the limit t tends to 0. ($e^0=1$)

we get

> $lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{t}{1-e^{2t}}$=

> $lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{t}{\left(1-e^t\right)\left(1+e^t\right)}$=

> $lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{t}{2\left(1-e^t\right)}$

Now using taylor series expansion for $e^x$ we easily get the limit as -1/2. Can you proceed or should I explain ahead?